# Quedarme con 2 decimales Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Consumo un servicio "x" el cual me brinda el saldo de las cuentas

por ejemplo em devolvera 98675.38282761

lo que necesito es quedarme solo con 2 decimales , actualmente obtengo el saldo y lo muestro en una label de la siguiente forma :

```
let balanceNumber = (messageRS["balance"] as? NSNumber)!
                        var balance = balanceNumber.stringValue
                        if(balance.isEmpty){
                            balance = (messageRS["availableBalance"] as? String)!
                        }
                        if(!balance.isEmpty){
                            self.strLblAccountBalance.text = newBalanceMsg.replacingOccurrences(of: "/(balance)/", with: balance)
                        }else{
                            self.strLblAccountBalance.text = newBalanceMsg.replacingOccurrences(of: "/(balance)/", with: "---")
                        }
```

Como podria solo imprimir el numero con 2 decimales

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar NSDecimalNumber que además te permite redondear.

```
var number: NSDecimalNumber = 12334445.4567721
    let behavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
    number = number.rounding(accordingToBehavior: behavior)

    print(number) // 12334445.46
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esta extensión se podría modificar el número de decimales. Si además necesitas un redondeo diferente, las opciones son:

- `.ceiling`: Redondea hacia el infinito positivo.
- `.floor`: Redondea hacia el infinito negativo.
- `.down`: Redondea hacia cero.
- `.up`: Redondea alejándose de cero.
- `.halfEven`: Redondea hacía el entero más cercano o hacia un número par si es equidistante.
- `.halfDown`: Redondea hacia el entero más cercano o hacia cero si es equidistante.
- `.halfUp`: Redondea hacia el entero más cercano o se aleja de cero si es equidistante.

```
extension Double {
    func redondear(numeroDeDecimales: Int) -> String {
        let formateador = NumberFormatter()
        formateador.maximumFractionDigits = numeroDeDecimales
        formateador.roundingMode = .down
        return formateador.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo:

```
let numeroPi: Double = 3.14159265359
print(numeroPi.redondear(numeroDeDecimales: 3)) // 3.141
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi de la siguiente forma

```
 let balanceNumber = (messageRS["balance"] as? Double)!
 var balance = String(format: "%.2f", balanceNumber)
```

Comment: Si esta fue tu forma de resolverlo, por favor márcala como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar esta extension

```
public extension FloatingPoint {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        let divisor = Self(Int(pow(10.0, Double(places))))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}

balanceNumber.rounded(toPlaces: 2)
```